# Simple OpenCV program won't run; given no errors. What now?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a term project for school and plan to use OpenCV. I've spent the past day or so battling include/link errors (mostly because of dumb mistakes) and finally have everything working. Or so I thought.

I have a simple program, that looks like this:

```
#include <highgui.h>
int main() {
    cvNamedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

No errors appear in Eclipse, and everything is bold-faced / looking as it should for the library functions (can't remember exactly what the proper formatting name is called). When I compile it, everything succeeds. No errors. But when I run this, nothing happens. And it's at this point I'm stuck.

I'm using OpenCV at work and modeled my setup at home accordingly (nearly identically actually). The include paths, library paths, and libraries are added properly in the project for Eclipse (at least, w.r.t my work setup). The DLL's are in the same folder as the executable.

Any ideas why this doesn't run? (The window doesn't display, it just instantly terminates)

I should mention that I'm using Eclipse (Helios), MinGW, Windows 7, and OpenCV 2.3.

Cheers.

Comment: You're most likely linking incorrectly. Try running the compiled exe from a command prompt. What happens?

Comment: I get this: "The procedure entry point _ZNSt9exceptionD2Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll."

Comment: I reinstalled MinGW, everything works. Why I start porjects in Windows baffles me sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: No worries :) For some reason Eclipse doesn't report linking errors. Happened to me all last semester ;]

Comment: I have the same problem, but I use QtCreator. I compiled the opencv libraries myself, but I still get the "The procedure entry point _ZNSt9exceptionD2Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll." error. I cleared everything, installed the latest stable version of Qt (4.8.1, was using 4.6.3) but the result is the same.

Comment: try to debug and see what int x = cvNamedWindow(bla bla) and int y = cvWaitKey() returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling from command prompt, than run executable from command prompt, see what happens. 
this is how I compile

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -I"C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv" -L"C:\OpenCV2.1\lib" -lcxcore210 -lcv210 -lhighgui210 -lcvaux210 -lml210
```

Note: that i have used opencv 2.1. so set your one accordingly. And also I have added `OpenCv bin folder to path`, so it makes it easier to find the dll files for the executable file.